# Behave how to specify different config file via cmd line?

Tags: python, python-behave

I am running behave tests with a default configuration file called behave.ini in the same directory. It is working perfectly fine.

However, for some reason, I need another configuration file called behave_alternative.ini.

Is it possible to specify the configuration file through the command line?

I am using `context.config.userdata` as a workaround now, yet specify a config file is better.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot act like this. However, you can use another approach (tox.ini, .behaverc) to load config for it:
https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/stable/behave.html#configuration-files
but your project root is the lowest level possible.

You can check the tree order of reading config files by putting -v flag to you command.

hope it helps a bit